# $AXX'=0$ vs $AX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Prove or disprove

If $AXX'=0$ then $AX=0$, where $A$ is a square matrix and $X$ is a rectangular matrix.

Update: $X'$ is the transpose of $X$ and the field of this vector space is the set of real numbers.

Comment: The only case that this is not true is that $X' \in Null(AX)$, but $X \notin Null(A)$. Can this happen?

Comment: I forgot, is $X'$ the transpose of $X$?

Comment: The result depends on the field. If the field is real, the statement is true. If it is some other field (e.g. GF(2)), the statement can be false. If you have a specific field in mind, please state it in the question.

Comment: I am looking for the reason though.

Comment: Can $XX'$ be in the null space of $A$, but $X$ is not in null space of $A$?

Comment: One bit of terminology - we don't usually talk about matrices being in the nullspace of another matrix. The nullspace is a vector space - a collection of vectors. You can talk about the columns of $X$ being in the nullspace of $A$, which I believe will be relevant here.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I meant.

Comment: Is it possible that $Col(XX') \subset Null(A)$, but $Col(X) \not \subset Null(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* $AXX^T=0$ implies that $\left[(AX)^T\right]^T(AX)^T=AXX^TA^T=0$. If $Y$ is a **real** (rectangular) matrix such that $Y^TY=0$, can you conclude that $Y=0$? What are the diagonal elements of $Y^TY$?